# Where the data-tier application version number is stored in a Visual Studio project?

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, version-numbering, data-tier-applications, visual-studio-project

I have an utility which fills version numbers in AssemblyInfo.cs files. Now I need to implement a functionality to adjust version numbers for Visual Studio Data-Tier applications (DACPAC).

I see that I can adjust the number manually if I open project properties and click the Data-Tier application Properties button. But I cannot find where this number is stored in project files, so I have no idea how to update it automatically from my utility.

Do you know, where is the version number stored?

Answer (score 6):

The properties do not appear in the .sqlproj file unless you change them from their default values.  When you do they will appear as follows:

```
<DacDescription>This is my description</DacDescription>
<DacApplicationName>Database.Application.Name</DacApplicationName>
<DacVersion>1.2.3.4</DacVersion>
```

Answer (score 2):

The dacpac version number doesn't appear to show up until after the first successful project build.  After that however, it shows up as  in .sqlproj file as shown below.

[image: Dacpac version number info]

Comment: Hm, that's weird, my .sqlproj files do not have any of the properties in the screenshot, although I have built the project and deployed it many times. Maybe they have changed something in the latest SQL Data Tools? Some days ago Visual Studio offered SSDT update and I accepted it.